# Hamiltonian Flows and Heisenberg picture of quantum mechanics

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, hamilton-equations

I am a math bachelor student studying Quantum Mechanics and I was very briefly introduced to the Heisenberg picture. (Hence many of the following may be trivial)

In particular what I know is that:

1. the exponentiation of the Hamiltonian $H$ yields (the adjoint of) the
   propagator operator $U=e^{\frac{itH}{h}}$
2. To any operator $A$ we can associate its evolved $A_t=U^+AU$ so that
   given an initial state $\psi_0$ the average of the expected value of
   A at time t is $<A>_t=(\psi_0,A_t\psi_0)$ and it holds the
   Heisenberg equation $\frac{d}{dt}A_t=\frac{1}{ih}[A_t,H]+\partial_t
   A_t$.
3. The exponantiation of operators other than the Hamiltonian, such as
   angular momemtum L, momentum p yields propagations in'dimensions'
   other than time, in the sense that if $T=e^{\frac{itL}{h}}$ then
   $T\psi(\rho,\phi,\theta)=\psi(\rho,\phi,\theta+t)$ (where L has been
   expressed in z-axis spherical coordinates). Analogously $
   T=e^{\frac{itp}{h}}$ then $T\psi(x)=\psi(x+t)$.

Now, in Hamiltonian mechanics we define Hamiltonian Flows as the group action $\phi_t$ associated to the solution $(x(t),p(t))$ of the 'generalized' Hamilton equations 
$$\frac{dx_k}{dt}=\partial_{p_k}F$$
$$\frac{dp_k}{dt}=-\partial_{x_k}F$$ 
so that $\phi_t(x(0),p(0))=(x(t),p(t))$.

$F$ may be the Hamiltonian, in which case we have time evolution of the system, but it may also be an affine function of position, so that we have (negative) momentum evolution (in the sense that $\phi_t(x,p)=(x,p-t)$) or of momentum  and we have spatial evolution (in the sense that $\phi_t(x,p)=(x+t,p)$). If finally F equals L we have rotations.

Now, I cannot fully and deeply explain, if it is possible, the parrallelism I notice. In particular:

1. Can we identify in some sense the exponentiation of operators  with
   the group action (of $\mathbb{S}^1$?) thus connecting the two
   scenarios?
2. What is the precise notion of 'dimensions' other than time, if any,  in which
   the system evolves?
3. In the Schroedinger picture, Ehrenfest theorem allows to find an
   analog to the Hamilton equations, is this possible also in the
   Heisenber picture (it may be through the Heisenberg Equation , bu I
   cannot make this precise), in particular, also in the cases $F\neq
   H$?

Comment: To your question number one, I'm not sure, but it sounds like you are knocking on the same door that led Feynman to develop the path integral fomalism of quantum mechanics.  So the answer, if I understand your question, is a qualified "yes".

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are trying to access [advective flows of Abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Lie's_data_transport_equation). Motion is a canonical transformation, so, in classical mechanics, it is a symplectomorphic flow, and in quantum mechanics, it is a [quantum flow](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf) in phase space. I'm not sure what   precise definition of "dimensions" ~ dynamical variables/observables is required.

Comment: @bob.sacamento thanks! Could you tell me a bit more about the connection to the little I know in Feynman picture we have an analogous of Action which is minimised by the most probable path.

Comment: @CosmasZachos thanks! I will check them out, so basically there exists a universal formalism comprising the two cases?

Comment: In [phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation) you can "segue" from quantum mechanics to classical mechanics, or vice versa... The booklet I linked to outlines the picture...

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta   There's no way I can do it justice in the space of a comment here.  I would suggest you take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation